# How to pass as a decorator of a class method of a class in Python?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a crud class that I want to reuse. But the problem is that the fastapi route.get decorator accepts url as a parameter, which I cannot dynamically substitute in the class method decorator in any way:

```
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter

CRUD = MyCRUD  # my special crud class
router = InferringRouter()


@cbv(router)
class CRUDEndpoint:
    crud: CRUD = Depends()

    @router.get(self.crud.url)  # <- how to substitute crud class attribute for ships?
    async def get_all(self, limit: int = None, offset: int = None):
        return await self.crud.get_all(limit, offset)
```

so that in another module you can inherit from the class and reuse its methods without overriding them:

```
@cbv(router)
class SpecificEndpoint(CRUDEndpoint):
    crud: SpecificCRUD = Depends()
```

UPDATED:

Thank you, chepner! This is what I was looking for!
But now I am facing a new problem in the create method.

I must pass a dependency as a parameter to the method, so that the endpoint accepts parameters in accordance with the scheme.
I am trying to decorate a function in the **init_subclass** method by passing it the scheme I need as a parameter, but for some reason this does not work (

```
    @cbv(router)
    class CRUDEndpoint:
    
        def __init_subclass__(cls, crud=None, router=None, **kwargs):
            super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
            if crud is not None:
                cls.crud = crud()
    
                cls.get_all = router.get(crud.url)(cls.get_all)
                cls.create = router.post(crud.url)(cls.create)(cls, params=cls.crud.create_schema)  # I tried to transfer the dependency (Depends(crud.create_schema) in different ways, it does not work
    
        async def get_all(self, limit: int = None, offset: int = None):
            return await self.crud.get_all(limit, offset)
    
        async def create(self, params: BaseModel = Depends(self.crud.create_schema)):
    
            if new_obj := await self.crud.create(data=self.crud.create_schema(**params.dict())):
                return new_obj
    
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ADi.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Does `CRUD` (the class) have a class attribute named `url` or not? If it does, I don't see the problem. If it doesn't, what URL are you expecting to pass to `router.get`?

Comment: I want to pass self.crud.url instead of CRUD.url


because I plan to inherit from this class in other modules where there will be a different CRUD
but
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Then you wanted `crud`, not `CRUD`. When the decorator is executed, there is no class yet, so no class attribute.; `crud` is just a name defined in the namespace of the `class` statement being executed. For a subclass, the new value of `crud` is defined too late to be used by the decorator.

Comment: yes, I understand why this is so, but I'm looking for a way to make the class independent of the specific CRUD so that it can be reused without overriding methods with a decorator

Comment: You might need to use `__init_subclass__`. The inherited method `get_all` is already defined (including the use of the decorator) by the time you define the subclass.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot, I'm already half way) Thank you! But there was another problem, edited the question.